# Wordpress unable to add Image to Page/Post

Tags: wordpress, debugging, upload

When creating a new page/post, I can't add images using the "Add Media" feature.

The image selected does not load on the editor. Google Inspect reveal the following error:

```
POST http://stss.org.sg/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,suggest,wp-ajax-respons…:445  404 (Not Found)
```

Have anyone encountered similar issue?

Wordpress Version: 4.7.4

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deactivating all the plugins and see of it works. If it works with all of the plugins disabled you can enable them one by one until it is broken again and you know it is a plugin problem.

If it is still broken try another theme and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, I couldn't insert single image into editor, even though inserting gallery of images worked ok. WordPress was already upgraded to latest version, all plugins were deactivated and default theme activated.

Finally I got it working after turning off ModSecurity in Cpanel for this domain.